# Inserting .readLine(); into my array of strings

Tags: java

im a new coder here.

**My program in a nutshell:** Im working on a fantasy football trade calculator using player values to understand what would be a good trade.

**My problem:** I am able read from my file, count the positions however unable to add my string to my array of playNames. I get null, please look at my iteration in the for loop line. I am curious to why im getting a null value? Any Idea on a fix?

*Thank you, Sincerely*
*Java Noob

```
        String filename="C:\\Users\\Karanvir\\Desktop\\21days\\players.txt";
        File filez=new File(filename);
        BufferedReader br;

        String[] playerNames = null;
        int counterOfReadLines=0;


        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filez));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            counterOfReadLines=counterOfReadLines+1;



            while(br.readLine() != null){

             System.out.println(br.readLine());
             counterOfReadLines=counterOfReadLines+1;

             playerNames=new String[counterOfReadLines];

            }

        for(int i=0;i<playerNames.length;i++){
    playerNames[i]=br.readLine();


        }
    br.close();
```

```html
Rob Gronkowski 48
Zach Ertz 34
Travis Kelce 29
Evan Engram 15
Jimmy Graham 12
Cameron Brate 10
Delanie Walker 9
Kyle Rudolph 6
Austin Seferian-Jenkins 6
Jack Doyle 6
Hunter Henry 5
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post a few lines out of the `players.txt` file?

Comment: ok one second sorry guys

Comment: hey guys made the adjustments, hope they are up to standards

Comment: @Karanvir1 This is too verbose. You need to show exactly which part of the code is giving you different behaviour than expected, and what behaviour you **would** expect.

Comment: The behavior that doesnt work, is in my for loop. For some reason, It wont add br.readLine to my string array. Hope this helps , sorry for wasting your time if I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        while(br.readLine() != null){

         System.out.println(br.readLine());
         counterOfReadLines=counterOfReadLines+1;

         playerNames=new String[counterOfReadLines];

        }

for(int i=0;i<playerNames.length;i++){
playerNames[i]=br.readLine();


    }
```

This just doesn't work at all:

```
        while(br.readLine() != null){
```

is reading a line, checking if it is null, then discarding it.

```
         System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

is reading another line, printing it, then discarding it.

```
         playerNames=new String[counterOfReadLines];
```

is creating a new array, filled with nulls.

You never put anything into the array.

Now:

```
for(int i=0;i<playerNames.length;i++){
playerNames[i]=br.readLine();


    }
```

OK, so you go back and try to read the right number of items from the `BufferedReader`. However, the reason you stopped the previous loop is because `br.readLine()` returned `null`, and [that's because you reached the end of the stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--).

You've already read all the data there is to be read here, so you just read a `null` on each iteration, and put that into the array element (which already is already set to `null`).

---

Instead, use a `List<String>`, which can grow - arrays cannot - and put items into that:

```
List<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<>();
String line;

// This reads a line, and stores it in a variable, so you can use
// the String you read inside the loop body.
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  // Don't need counterOfReadLines, just use playerNames.size().
  playerNames.add(line);
}
```

Comment: wow thanks man, I like your answer. Im still a noob, do you have any tips for me? Why is growth my array important here, if Im using a array with the defined number of players? I apprecitate your help!

Comment: "Why is growth my array important here" in part for when you're *not* using a defined number of players any more. You can use a fixed-size array if you want, but you're just making unnecessary work for yourself: you then have to keep track of the number of elements in the list you've already assigned, so you know which element to assign next, how many to use etc.

Comment: Thanks , im changing my code as we speak. As for my array, which I was using earlier do you mind telling me why it didnt work? Just so I know for the future, and can not make the same mistake. I see its reading and then discarding, but would it of been possible using a normal array? whats wrong with my logic, so I can think more like you. Your obviously king of code, Software Engineer at google!

Comment: As I have already explained: you were never adding the data you have read from the file into the array. You read it, and discard it.

Answer (score 0):

The normal usage of readLine is:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
for (;;) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) { // End of input reached.
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(line);
    lines.add(line);
}

for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Arrays do not grow, so better use an ArrayList.

Comment: This seems really complicated, I apprectiate your answer alot. I have assigned my array length to what is needed to hold all the values by incrementing everytime a line is read. Is it possible to solve my question using my similar style of code? Or should I just start using arrayLists?

Comment: As a further point, you can always use `toArray(new String[0])` if you really need an array.  Also, the `String line=null; while((line=br.readline()) != null){...` version of the loop always reads easier to my mind, but maybe that's just because I say it first. @Andy Turner added a full example with explanation while I was originally commenting